# Parent scroll view does not scroll if the child element also a scroll view

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a vertical scroll view in my unity application , and this scroll view has a child scroll view which scrolls horizontally, now the problem is that if i want to scroll the parent scroll view by touching upon the child scroll view it doesn’t scroll, please help

yeah, i tried to remove raycast target from all elements of child scroll view, but then the child scroll view won’t scroll at all